# visual studio resetting the cursor position when i open some documents

Tags: visual-studio

VS 2022 Version 17.6.2

how to recreate!

1. I open an xml document, by double clicking the file in solution explorer move the cursor down.
2. I double click the file in solution explorer again, it resets the cursor to the top of the window.

If I do that with any other filetype, even xslt, it doesnt.

very odd.

its as if VS reopens the file if its xml, but not if its not.

P.S.

chat gpt told me to
"Tools" -> "Options." -> "Projects and Solutions" -> "General." -> "Track Active Item in Solution Explorer."
and check it.

that didnt work!

Comment: your problem still continues?

Comment: yes, what about you?

Comment: I got the problem too, did you report it? if so give us the link to upvote, comment & help the issue to be resolved

Comment: no i havent, do u have xml tools installed as an extension? i did wonder if it was related to that?

Comment: I created an issue [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/When-a-solution-is-closed-and-reopened-v/10481334?sort=newest)